# AWS DynamoDB unexpected end of input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS and I tried to make a Lambda function that posts items in my dynamodb table. I get this error:

```
Request: /appshop
Status: 200
Latency: 1645 ms
Response Body

{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

However, status is 200 and it passed, but not created item in my table. How do I solve this?

Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2'});


exports.handler = (event) => {
  const shopId = 'myshopid'

    const params = {
      Item: {
            ShopId: "User_" + Math.random(),
            name: event.name,
            address: event.address,
            city: event.city
        },
        TableName: "milos-Shop"
      
    }
    
 dynamoDB.putItem(params, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return(err);
      }else{
        console.log(data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
})
```

My request body for post:

```
{
    "name": "TEST shop",
    "address": "TEST address",
    "city": "TEST city"
}
```

And my table has those also. Name, address, and city. They are correctly spelled and they are strings too.

Comment: Missing final closing brace.

Comment: Now it passes but nothing is written in dynamodb

Comment: What do your logs (in CloudWatch Logs) tell you?